# Python store value from SQL request into a variable

Tags: python

this is the code I have in Python:

```
for y in cursor.fetchone():
# for test - print current product attribute ID
print("Updated at Id_product_attribute: " + str(y))

# I want to select ID stock based on Id_product_attribute
idStockAvailble = "SELECT id_stock_available FROM ps_stock_available WHERE id_product_attribute = " + str(y) + ";"
cursor.execute(idStockAvailble)

# for test - print stock ID 
print("Id stock availble: " + str(idStockAvailble))
```

When I print "idStockAvailble" i get:

Id stock availble: SELECT id_stock_available FROM ps_stock_available WHERE id_product_attribute = 136;

How can I get the value of "id_stock_available "

Comment: After the execute: `res = cursor.fetchall()`  then you can iterate it.

Comment: In case the sql is design to return 1 record use `fetchone`. Ref: https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/

Comment: Thanks I figured it out